# Apache Spark Lambda Expression - Serialization Issue

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, apache-spark

I have tried to use lambda expression in spark task, and it throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lambda deserialization" exception. This exception is thrown when the is code like "transform(pRDD->pRDD.map(t->t._2))" . The code snippet is below.

```
JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> aggregate = pairRDD.reduceByKey((x,y)->x+y);
JavaDStream<Integer> con = aggregate.transform(
(Function<JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>, JavaRDD<Integer>>)pRDD-> pRDD.map( 
(Function<Tuple2<String,Integer>,Integer>)t->t._2));


JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> aggregate = pairRDD.reduceByKey((x,y)->x+y);
JavaDStream<Integer> con = aggregate.transform(
(Function<JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>, JavaRDD<Integer>> & Serializable)pRDD-> pRDD.map( 
(Function<Tuple2<String,Integer>,Integer> & Serializable)t->t._2));
```

The above two options didn't worked. Where as if I pass below object "f" as the argument instead of lambda expression"t->t_.2". It works.

```
Function f = new Function<Tuple2<String,Integer>,Integer>(){
@Override
public Integer call(Tuple2<String,Integer> paramT1) throws Exception {
return paramT1._2;
}
};
```

May I know what is the right format to express that functions as a lambda expression.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Function f = new Function<Tuple2<String,Integer>,Integer>(){

                @Override
                public Integer call(Tuple2<String,Integer> paramT1) throws Exception {
                    return paramT1._2;
                }

            };

            JavaStreamingContext ssc = JavaStreamingFactory.getInstance();

            JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);
            JavaDStream<String> words =  lines.flatMap(s->{return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));});
            JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> pairRDD =  words.mapToPair(x->new Tuple2<String,Integer>(x,1));
            JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> aggregate = pairRDD.reduceByKey((x,y)->x+y);
            JavaDStream<Integer> con = aggregate.transform(
                    (Function<JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>, JavaRDD<Integer>>)pRDD-> pRDD.map( 
                            (Function<Tuple2<String,Integer>,Integer>)t->t._2));
          //JavaDStream<Integer> con = aggregate.transform(pRDD-> pRDD.map(f)); It works
            con.print();

            ssc.start();
            ssc.awaitTermination();


        }
```

Comment: May I ask why do you wish to serialize lambda expressions as it is, like for inner classes, the serialization of lambda expressions is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @eliasah In spark serialization of lambda expressions is a very standard and expected operation. It's a parallel execution engine that serializes jobs to run remotely.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the lambda doesn't work. Perhaps the problem is with a lambda nested inside a lambda. This seems to be recognized by the Spark documentation.

Contrast the example from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#basics:

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("data.txt");
JavaRDD<Integer> lineLengths = lines.map(s -> s.length());
int totalLength = lineLengths.reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
```

With the example from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transform-operation:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
// RDD containing spam information
final JavaPairRDD<String, Double> spamInfoRDD = jssc.sparkContext().newAPIHadoopRDD(...);

JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> cleanedDStream = wordCounts.transform(
  new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>, JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override public JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> call(JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> rdd) throws Exception {
      rdd.join(spamInfoRDD).filter(...); // join data stream with spam information to do data cleaning
      ...
    }
  });
```

The second example uses a `Function` subclass instead of a lambda, presumably because of the same issue that you discovered.

I don't know whether this is useful for you, but the nested lambdas certainly work in Scala. Consider the Scala version of the previous example:

```
val spamInfoRDD = ssc.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(...) // RDD containing spam information

val cleanedDStream = wordCounts.transform(rdd => {
  rdd.join(spamInfoRDD).filter(...) // join data stream with spam information to do data cleaning
  ...
})
```

Comment: It's (clearly) not a full answer, sorry. Feel free to downvote if it's useless!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes nested lambda is not being recognised in Apache Spark

Comment: Just be sure to remember that anonymous classes are not static classes.  They have a pointer to their parent object which will also be serialized by spark, which is probably not what you intend. It's probably safer to use a named static inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that lambda functions in Java are really a "class" which implements an interface inside the package java.util.function, for example Interface Function (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). I see that this interfaces doesn't extend Serializable... and here is the point...

... when you are using lambda inside a Spark function... Spark is trying to serialize the lambda "class".. and it doesn't implements Serializable.

You could try to force Serializable with something like this:

```
Runnable r = (Runnable & Serializable)() -> System.out.println("Serializable!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try boxing the return-value you're trying to send:
return new Integer(paramT1._2);

I'm suggesting this because of the source suggesting that int's aren't serializable:
http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered the similar issue, and the way I solved this issue is to simply create a `SerializableFunction` as following

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Function;

interface SerializableFunction<T, R> extends Function<T, R>, Serializable {
}
```

And replace all your `Function`s with `SerializableFunction`

```
private static final SerializableFunction<Row, Boolean> SAMPLE_FUNCTION = row -> {
    final String userId = row.getAs("user_id");
    return userId != null;
};
```